# Use Google Scripts to upload xlsx file from Windows File System to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an .xlsx file on the Windows File System on my laptop.  I can upload the file to my Google Docs by manually creating a Google Sheet on my Google Drive and using the Google Sheet menu: "File|Import|Upload" commands to manually upload the .xlsx file as shown in the attached image.

My on-line research returned articles on scripts which can import a file that is already on the internet with existing URL but not in my Google Docs.
My question is how can I perform the same function as the manual Google Sheet menu: "File|Import|Upload" using a Google Apps Script?
[Google Sheets Manual Upload Process Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64CjX.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.